# Starting process with NICE Command (macOS) leaves the process priority at 0

Tags: macos, bash, process, command, nice

I have a script (extendscript for AE) that create a command file and execute it.
the generated command file look like:

```
FILE=/path/file
VAR="nice -n 9 ./application  $FILE "
cd /Applications/applicationpath
$VAR
```

Once my script is launching by the application I run :
`ps -lp {processID}` on terminal and I get NI = 0 whatever the number I put after `nice -n`
If I manually renice the process, then `ps -lp` displays the correct process priority

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It works fine for me, in 10.6.8.

Comment: does ps -lp return you the correct priority? i am on 10.10.3

Comment: I did `ps -l`, and it showed `PRI=22` and `NI=9`. `ps -lp` complains that `-p` requires an argument. Also had `N` in the `S` column

Comment: Ok I understood where I messed Up. The program Launched is starting multiple process and it is these process that  are ressource intensive and would need to be renice. however I dont know how to access them in order to renice them. 
anyway thanks everybody! 
is it posible to renice a process without knowing its PID?

Comment: If they're truly child processes, they should inherit the priority. But if they're being launched through `launchd` (like most windowed applications), the priority won't be passed along. There might be some way to tell `launchd` to nice a process before it starts it. apple.stackexchange.com would probably be a good place to ask.

Comment: thanks ! I'll post over there :)